ElasticSearch - Implementing both exact SKU matching and general fuzzy search
I'm working on a Remix project where I need to achieve two key behaviors with Elasticsearch:

Exact SKU Search: When the user enters a product SKU (e.g.,
SUMT/R-2DK2), I want Elasticsearch to return only that product.
General Term Search: When a general term is entered, Elasticsearch should use fuzzy matching to return multiple relevant products across productName, productVariantName, description, and other fields.

No matter what approach I tried, I can't get Elasticsearch to prioritize and return only the exact SKU when provided, without impacting the general fuzzy search behavior negatively. Either the fuzzy search gets blocked, or the SKU search isn't exclusive enough, leading to mixed results.
Question
How can I configure Elasticsearch to strictly return only the exact SKU match when it's given, while also supporting broad fuzzy matching for general search terms?
I'm open to suggestions for query structure, dynamic query branching, or any other Elasticsearch features that might help achieve this goal. Thanks in advance!
Here is my config:
searchConfig: {
  multiMatchType: 'most_fields',
  boostFields: {
    productName: 1,
    productVariantName: 1,
    description: 1,
    sku: 2,
  },
  mapQuery: (query, input, searchConfig, channelId, enabledOnly) => {
    if (!query.bool) {
      query.bool = {};
    }
    if (query.bool.must) {
      delete query.bool.must;
      query.bool.must = [];
    }
    query.bool.should = query.bool.should || [];

    if (input.term) {
      query.bool.should.push({
        term: {
          sku: {
            value: input.term,
            boost: 2,
          },
        },
      });

      query.bool.should.push({
        multi_match: {
          query: input.term,
          type: 'most_fields',
          fuzziness: 'AUTO',
          fields: [
            `productName^${searchConfig.boostFields.productName}`,
            `productVariantName^${searchConfig.boostFields.productVariantName}`,
            `description^${searchConfig.boostFields.description}`,
          ],
        },
      });

      query.bool.minimum_should_match = 1;
    }

    return query;
  }

This is the query that it generates:
{
  "bool": {
    "filter": [
      {
        "term": {
          "channelId": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "languageCode": "hu"
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "enabled": true
        }
      }
    ],
    "must": [],
    "should": [
      {
        "term": {
          "sku": {
            "value": "SUMT/R-2DK2",
            "boost": 2
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "prefix_search": {
          "query": "SUMT/R-2DK2",
          "type": "most_fields",
          "fuzziness": "AUTO",
          "fields": [
            "productName^1",
            "productVariantName^1",
            "description^1"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "minimum_should_match": 1
  }
}


Any help would be greatly appreciated!

As per my experience, it is not possible with single query. You can create 2 different query - one for SKU search and one for fuzzy search and if SKU result available then render that one and if not available then render fuzzy result. You can check _msearch multi search where you can pass two queries in single request and get response in same order.
